# AS3 How to reverse Vector List

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, vector

I use setTimeout for server connection and when i connect i want to reverse my Vector list. How i reverse my vector list ?

My Vector variable class

```
public class UriIterator 
{
     private var _availableAddresses: Vector.<SocketConnection> = new Vector.<SocketConnection>();
     private var currentIndex:int = 0;

    public function UriIterator(){

    }


    public function withAddress(host: String, port: int): UriIterator {
        const a: SocketConnection = new SocketConnection(host, port);
        _availableAddresses.push(a);
        return this;
    }


     public function get next():SocketConnection {
        var address = _availableAddresses[currentIndex];
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex > _availableAddresses.length - 1)
            currentIndex = 0;
        return address;
    }




}
```

and init my vector list like that

```
public static const urisToTry: UriIterator = new UriIterator()

urisToTry.withAddress("https:// 123", 1234);
urisToTry.withAddress("https:// 123", 1234);
urisToTry.withAddress("https:// 123", 1234);
urisToTry.withAddress("https:// 123", 1234);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reverse() works the same on vectors as on arrays.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4.html

Comment: when i try this --> urisToTry._availableAddresses.reverse();  and check with trace log don't reverse. Why ?